# SQLAlchemy ORM: modify WHERE clause

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy, where-clause

If I've been given a Query object that I didn't construct, is there a way to directly modify its WHERE clause?  I'm really hoping to be able remove some AND statements or replace the whole FROM clause of a query instead of starting from scratch.

I'm aware of the following methods to modify the SELECT clause:

Query.with_entities(), Query.add_entities(), Query.add_columns(), Query.select_from()

which I think will also modify the FROM.  And I see that I can view the WHERE clause with Query.whereclause, but the docs say that it's read-only.

I realize I'm thinking in SQL terms, but I'm more familiar with those concepts than the ORM, at this point.  Any help is very appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can modify query._whereclause directly, but I'd seek to find a way to not have this issue in the first place - whereever it is that the Query is generated should be factored out so that the non-whereclause version is made available.

Comment: I would certainly prefer to ask the query "what are you, so far?", and reconstruct that parts I want from scratch, but I don't know how to do that either.  I can:

    
`query.whereclause.clauses = [mytable.name.in(['jim', 'bob'])]`

I ran a quick test without error.  Is this likely to break anything?